# How to turn off alternative Enter with Ctrl+M in Linux

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

Why is Ctrl+M bound to Enter in Ubuntu Jaunty? How to turn it off?

I'm using Emacs and would like to bind Ctrl+M to some other command.

Comment: Linux is a too general term, you will at least need to tell us which distribution and terminal emulator you're running.

Comment: @adamse: I've got Ubuntu Jaunty.

Comment: Am removing linux tag because it's nothing to do with Linux.

Comment: @Trey: I was not initially sure where I neede to change the key binding in Linux or in Emacs, but the answers came out to be about Emacs. However now I'm pretty sure I need to change the binding in Linux so I'm creating a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299142/how-to-assign-newline-functionality-in-ubuntu-jaunty-to-enter-directly.

Answer (score 35):

I think your question is backwards. It is not <kbd>C-m</kbd> that is bound to <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it is Enter that is bound to <kbd>C-m</kbd>. And <kbd>C-m</kbd> is the same as `RET`.

If you run <kbd>C-h k C-m</kbd>, you will see something like "`RET runs the command ...`". <kbd>C-m</kbd> sends `RET` because it is a control code, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character.

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is bound to <kbd>C-m</kbd>; if you run <kbd>C-h k Enter</kbd>, you will see something like "`RET (translated from <return>) runs the command ...`". See, <kbd>Enter</kbd> is being interpreted by emacs as <return> and then that key is getting translated to <kbd>C-m</kbd>.

What you want to do is first remove the translation from <return> to `RET` by binding it directly to what it's currently indirectly bound, e.g. `(global-set-key (kbd "<return>") 'newline)`. Then you're free to bind <kbd>C-m</kbd> to whatever you want without affecting Enter.

This assumes you're using the graphical emacs. If you're running it in a terminal, this won't work, because Enter will send C-m, not <return>. You can check that using the `window-system` variable though.

Comment: 'C-h k' runs the command 'describe-key', which will ask you which key you want to describe, then pop up a help buffer which tells you what command the key is bound to and what that command does.

Comment: "Then you're free to bind C-m to whatever you want without affecting Enter." - well.. wrong! For one thing the recipe breaks <return> behavior in minibuffer context.

Answer (score 8):

*Note:* The issue isn't limited to Linux, it exists on Windows (and presumably Mac) as well.  Read the other (non stack-overflow) source of all knowledge: [Wikipedia on Carriage Return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return).

If you want to rebind <kbd>C-m</kbd>, be sure to all bind <kbd><return></kbd> otherwise you run the risk of no longer being able to use the Enter/Return key.  Also, in a terminal, Emacs cannot distinguish between the two (<kbd>C-m</kbd> and <kbd><return></kbd>).

In a plain Emacs, the Enter/Return key is bound to <kbd><return></kbd>, which is (by default) translated to <kbd>RET</kbd> (same thing as <kbd>C-m</kbd>).  If you only rebound the <kbd>C-m</kbd>, you'd also be affecting the Enter/Return key.

Try <kbd>C-h k <return></kbd> and you'll see

> RET (translated from <return>)

So, rebind both in the appropriate keymap to make sure you get the behavior you want.

It might be instructive to play with the following code:

```
(defun my-return ()
  (interactive)
  (message "return"))
(defun my-ret ()
  (interactive)
  (message "RET"))
(defun my-c-m ()
  (interactive)
  (message "C-m"))
(global-set-key (kbd "<return>") 'my-return)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-m") 'my-c-m)
(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'my-ret)
```

Put that in your `*scratch*` buffer and press <kbd>C-j</kbd> after each line (to evaluate the sexp).  Then play with the Enter/Return keys and <kbd>C-m</kbd>.

Answer (score 5):

`input-decode-map` does the trick. Quote from the emacs manual:

> This keymap has the same structure as other keymaps, but is used differently: it specifies translations to make while reading key sequences, rather than bindings for key sequences.

It's the same principle like I've presented above, transforming <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> to something, say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
and map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to your command. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> for `backward-kill-word`.

Here you go:

```
(global-set-key (read-kbd-macro "C-1") 'backward-kill-word)
(define-key input-decode-map "\C-m" [?\C-1])
```

Comment: This works most of the time. A problem that I've seen using this, is when I'm trying to escape i-search mode with RET , it executes backward-kill-word.

Comment: `(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-m") [?\C-6])
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-6") [?\C-m])
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "<return>") [?\C-m])`
What do you think about that @StefanH? Seems to work - no search mode trouble or like. But I'm not emacs expert, so any thoughts? :)

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear whether the previous answers have solved this question, so here's another spin on it:

Historically, "<kbd>return</kbd>" frequently meant two things: Carriage Return, and Line Feed.

Quoting [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return):

> Originally, carriage return was the
>   term for a mechanism or lever on a
>   typewriter that would cause the
>   cylinder on which the paper was held
>   (the carriage) to return to the left
>   side of the paper after a line of text
>   had been typed, and would usually move
>   the paper to the next line as well.
>   Later it was used for the control
>   character in Baudot code on a
>   teletypewriter for end of line return
>   to beginning of line and did not
>   include line feed.

Long story short, there are two ASCII codes that are relevant to end-of-line (and, therefore, potentially to the return key): CR (ASCII decimal 13, or <kbd>Ctrl-m</kbd>) and LF (ASCII decimal 10, or <kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd>).

I think the general convention these days is for the <kbd>return</kbd> or <kbd>enter</kbd> keys to map to ASCII 13, and thus be "return" (`RET` in emacs messaging).  But if you're running emacs from a terminal emulator, this may mean that you don't have the option of having a <kbd>C-m</kbd> binding that's different from `RET`.  When I try running emacs in a terminal (GNU Emacs 23.2.1 on MacOS X in Terminal.app), and I try typing <kbd>C-h c <return></kbd> (i.e. pressing my return/enter key), I get:

```
RET runs the command newline
```

If I type, instead, <kbd>C-h c C-m</kbd> (i.e. holding down control and pressing M), I get:

```
RET runs the command newline
```

In other words, the exact same thing.  Emacs (nor any other program run from the terminal) can't tell the difference between the two.  (Knowing this can sometimes be handy -- if you're logged in to a system that maps things differently than the system you're coming from, you can type <kbd>C-m</kbd> or <kbd>C-j</kbd> to get the thing you want, depending on the way the mapping is screwed up.)

And speaking of having the mapping screwed up, I'll just mention that there are some `stty` settings that can be relevant to such things: `inlcr`, `inlcr`, and `igncr` (these three are related to how input is processed -- there are also some output-related ones).  I doubt that making stty changes is going to be useful to this particular problem, but I thought it worth mentioning.

In the end, I think your choices are:

1. Live with not having <kbd>C-m</kbd> that means anything different than <kbd>return</kbd>/<kbd>enter</kbd>
2. Run a graphical version of emacs, instead of the terminal version.  This should have access to the distinct keycodes, which the terminal emulator isn't passing along (because it's emulating a terminal, which didn't have such things in the same way as modern computers do).

Answer (score 2):

(global-set-key (kbd "C-m") 'cmd) ;

Where **cmd** is your command should remap control m...

As for why ctrl+m is bound to enter. I believe it had something to do with some older keyboard not having enter,tab, backspace, etc... ( I could be grossly mistaken)

For example ctrl+h is backspace, some unix operating systems will output ^H when you hit backspace on them!

Comment: Okay, what I wanted to say is that since Enter is interpreted as <return> and it in its turn is translated to RET, Enter starts to work as cmd as well as Ctrl+m.

Comment: Saves 'pinky stretch' on my keyboard, so I actually find it rather handy when used with the Ctrl --> Caps Lock remap. One less reason to leave the home keys. Perhaps this was more pronounced on earlier keyboards?

Answer (score 2):

The main source of the problem is that Enter and Ctrl-M both map to the same ASCII code (13). You would only be able to map them distinctly on a system that can distinguish them.

Comment: Ctrl-M is synonymous with ASCII (decimal) code 13, which is CR (Carriage Return).  There's also code 10, a.k.a. Ctrl-J, a.k.a. NL (New Line), or sometimes called LF (Line Feed).  It's true that the return/enter key is often mapped to the former, but that's not *always* the case.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is a very tricky question, you won't get it right with:
(global-set-key (kbd "") 'newline)

because that return (RET) is newline in just some particular cases. You will see the weirdness I'm talking about if you try that in your .emacs

I've found an ugly but working solution by using some KDE events application,  and bound Ctrl+m to Ctrl+1 . I've chosen that because I wouldn't use that combination (Ctrl+1) but you can choose something else.
This way, in emacs (but in my X environment) I don't get the RET (or linefeed character) when I press Ctrl+m, instead I get Ctrl+1.
And then, I did something like:
(global-set-key "\C-1" 'mycmd)

The problem is, that now I use awesome window manager, and I don't know how to do that X mapping again. 
If you don't use KDE, you search for something similar in Gnome.

Answer (score 2):

Some very good explanations here as to the nature of the problem, and I won't expound on those issues. However, I want to address the original question directly. I solved the problem for changing the `(control m)` sequence bound to `'newline` command by the following code in my `~/.xemacs/custom.el` file:

```
(defun my-compile-hook-for-c-and-cpp-mode ()
  "My compile hook for C and C++ mode" 
  (local-set-key [(control m)] 'compile)
  )

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-compile-hook-for-c-and-cpp-mode)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-compile-hook-for-c-and-cpp-mode)
```

In the above example, I have changed `(control m)` to run the `'compile` command (`M-x compile`) when the `c-mode` or `c++-mode` is active.

Note that you can change the behavior of `(control m)` globally as well, without the mode related bindings. In that case, just add the following to your `~/.xemacs/custom.el` file:

```
(global-set-key [(control m)] 'compile)
```

Comment: PS: I just checked with emacs 23 as well, and you can add these lisp statements in the `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file and they work just as described above.

Comment: Emacs 24 here. This still rebinds the return key.